# How to measure Performance in .NET

Tags: .net, performance

How can I measure the performance of an application in .NET?  Are there any frameworks for this? Performance means time taken by certain functions, CPU utilization and all such metrics.

Comment: You can use a profiler or simple `StopWatch` class.

Comment: Actually I am looking for a framework which will do everything for me with some configuration like instrumentation framework.

Comment: Asking for tools or framework is off topic in stackoverflow. [Refer 4th point](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)